# Eliminate characters in data.frame before a specific value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a file with a first column called "ID". This columns has information of which I only need the last one.

`k__Archaea;p__Euryarchaeota;c__Methanobacteria;o__Methanobacteriales;f__Methanobacteriacea`

I would like to eliminate all the characters before "f__", keeping only "Methanobacteriacea" in the first column.

What is a simple way to do this using R?

Answer (score 0):

One option is `sub`.  We match zero or more characters (`.*`) followed by `;`, then `f__` and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub(".*;f__", "", str1)
#[1] "Methanobacteriacea"
```

If we need from `f__`, then capture the characters starting from `f`as a group and replace it with the backreference for that group (`\\1`)

```
sub(".*;(f__.*)", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "f__Methanobacteriacea"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "k__Archaea;p__Euryarchaeota;c__Methanobacteria;o__Methanobacteriales;f__Methanobacteriacea"
```